# Is it possible to close the source File (file.close();) in java?

Tags: java, file, notepad

I am create a new file

```
File f = new File(file_path);
```

then the end of program can i possible to close that the file object or file?

```
f.close();
```

else there is a method is possible to close file??

```
     public class etest2read {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File("input");

    String source = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "TestFile.txt";
    //String TestFileone = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "TestFileone.txt";

    File fin = new File(source);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    System.out.println("file/folder: "+fin.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("file/folder: "+dir.getCanonicalPath());
    System.out.println("file/folder: "+fin.lastModified());


    String strLine;

     //Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
   // Print the content on the console
    System.out.println (strLine);
    }

  //Close the input stream
    br.close();
    System.out.println("Closed Buffered Reader");
    fis.close();
    System.out.println("Closed File Input Stream");

    fin.close(); // providing the error
       }
   }
```

Comment: Why do you want to close the file? If you are done with it you can just set the reference to null. If you want to make it read only just call File.setReadOnly().

Answer (score 6):

No it is not possible.

A File is an abstract representation of a file or directory pathname. You do not open the File, only a Stream or a Reader on that File.

Comment: it is possible to open the file?? but i know there is the function of file.close(); how it can be used??

Comment: @surendhiranbalagur - `File` class doesn't have `open()` and `close()` functions (those methods make no sense for a File). You can pass a file object to a `Reader` or a `Stream` and  close the Reader / Stream (which will be opened when you try to make a read call)

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only *close* the instances of objects that implement the *Closeable* interface (example `Reader` , `InputStream` etc). `File` class doesn't implement `Closeable`. Like *Burkhard* says, it is merely an abstract representation of the underlying file/ directory